# Problems detecting button pressed when waking up a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, button, detection

I'm designing a device to activate a mechanism when a specific number code is typed on a keytpad. In order to save battery life (it is powered by 3 AA batteries), I have configured the MCU to go to [EM4 (shut off mode, SiLabs)](https://www.silabs.com/mcu/32-bit-microcontrollers/efm32-energy-modes).
EM4 to EM0 timing is 163us, as stated in [MCU Data Sheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32tg-datasheet.pdf), page 30.

The locker has a button keypad with 12 metal domes connected to the MCU using a 4 rows/3 columns topology.

The MCU is programmed to wake up when detecting that any button is pressed.

The problem I'm having is that, about 75% of the times, when having the MCU in EM4 and pressing a button, the MCU wakes up but, when scanning which of the buttons is pressed (this is, column and row number), the MCU is not capable of doing it, so the first button value is not detected.

This is critical as the first button must be detected to assure a good user experience and to avoid typing a wrong code.

Several solutions come to my head but none of them are easy to implement or have several flaws.

#### Assigning a unique button to wake up the MCU

My MCU has already all GPIOs connected so this is not possible

#### Adding a cap to each button

This would imply a bad UX when typing following digits;
HW redesign required; BOM Costs increase

#### Configure MCU to switch to EM3 instead of EM4 and apply a periodic task to turn on GPIOs and scan

This turns current consumption from ~10 μA to ~200 μA (estimated)

#### Add an additional peripheric to the device to retain the value and be capable of turning on the device 100% of the times, using an I2C multiplexer

HW redesign required; BOM Costs increase

Does anyone have any additonal idea or possible solution to this problem? As always, there's a trade off between costs, lifespan and functionality...

Comment: How long does it currently take from that the button is pressed, to that the MCU is initiated "enough" to detect a key press? I think this should be possible, if the startup routine is done right. What is the maximum time acceptable, that one has to press a button without risking it is missed?

Comment: So we're talking about an EFM32?  Is the keypad matrix triggering a wake interrupt?  Text says it wakes in 2µs, that's much faster than a button.  Sure you're not getting bounce?

Comment: What the MCU is **capable** of and what the user's code does can be quite different. If user puts a 50ms init routine in front of the keypad scan loop, then that could be the issue, having little to do with MCU capabilities.  I suggest adding a GPIO debug output before the keyscan loop and then measure time from initial keypress to GPIO output to verify this is in ms range or less.

Comment: design the lock with the `press # to start` behavior

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I'll check the startup timing routines and come back with the data

Comment: Can it use the pin change interrupt to wake up from EM3 then scan? If so there is no reason to wake up periodically to scan the keyboard. Even with EM4, 163µs is pretty short, but then it will completely reboot, so the startup code could take a while especially if it has to load all the code/data into RAM...